# swagger documentation for hybris

Tags: rest, maven, swagger, pom.xml, sap-commerce-cloud

I need to generate rest api documentation using swagger for hybris.

I got Kongchan's sample pom.xml, but I couldn't really modify to match with hybris code. Can anyone pls provide me sample pom.xml for hybris or any links or documents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the [Wiki](https://help.hybris.com/6.7.0/hcd/99783546e09949e2b4bf27795b889464.html) for generating Hybris API Documentation with Swagger

---

**Edit:**

You can follow [spring-xml-swagger](https://github.com/springfox/springfox-demos/tree/master/spring-xml-swagger) example to integrate it with Hybris using XML configuration. Also, [this](https://experts.hybris.com/questions/55603/do-hybris-support-swagger-integration.html) and [this](https://experts.hybris.com/questions/81942/integrating-swagger-with-occ-layer-ycommercewebser.html) posts will help you.

Comment: Am getting error as Target "wsStaticDoc" does not exist in the project "platform"

Comment: Is this applicable to Hybris 6.4 version?

Comment: No, I think it comes with 6.5

Comment: I have edited my answer with more references which could help you to integrate it

Answer (score 0):

Here is the class I use for OCC (tested on hybris 6.6)

```
  import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
  import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
  import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
  import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
  import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport;

  import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
  import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
  import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
  import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
  import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
  import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
  import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;


  /**
   * @author ajaninmanificat Spring configuration for swagger. Only available if spring profile "swagger" is enabled.
   *
   */
  @Configuration
  @EnableSwagger2
  @Profile("swagger")
  public class SwaggerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport
  {


    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.addResourceHandler("**/swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket api()
    {
        final ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfoBuilder().title("OCC API documentation")
                .description("This document contains the generated API documentation for Omni Commerce Connect v2.")
                .version("Version v2").build();

        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any()).paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build().apiInfo(apiInfo).useDefaultResponseMessages(false).enableUrlTemplating(true);
    }


  }
```

---

**To enable Swagger you have to set this property** : `spring.profiles.active=swagger`. The idea is to prevent Swagger from being loaded in production.

To avoid any troubles with `BaseSiteMatchingFilter` I suggest to create a subclass `IgnorableBaseSiteMatchingFilter`

```
  import java.io.IOException;

  import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
  import javax.servlet.ServletException;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


  public class IgnorableBaseSiteMatchingFilter extends BaseSiteMatchingFilter
  {
    private String regexpIgnore;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response,
            final FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException
    {

        final boolean shouldIgnore = (regexpIgnore != null) && matchesUrl(request, regexpIgnore);
        if (shouldIgnore)
        {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
        else
        {
            // Is not ignored, call the real stuff
            super.doFilterInternal(request, response, filterChain);
        }
    }

    public void setRegexpIgnore(final String regexpIgnore)
    {
        this.regexpIgnore = regexpIgnore;
    }
  }
```

And the bean declaration looks like this :

```
<alias alias="baseSiteMatchingFilter" name="myBaseSiteMatchingFilter" />
<bean id="myBaseSiteMatchingFilter" class="mypackage.IgnorableBaseSiteMatchingFilter" parent="defaultBaseSiteMatchingFilter">
    <property name="regexpIgnore" value="(swagger|api-docs|info|login|logout|/health/|/css/|/img/|/js/|/font-awesome/|/bootstrap/|/assets/|/node_modules/)" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I tried the above solution and i get below exception can anyone help me on what i am missing ?org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/swagger-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/swagger-servlet.xml]

Comment: @user964819 The error says the file is not found. What is swagger-servlet.xml? It's not part of my solution.

Comment: i also referred to https://experts.hybris.com/questions/55603/do-hybris-support-swagger-integration.html and  added the files mentioned here.